# Show progress on html file input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to show a progress bar or spinner when I choose a file for upload, I'm not talking about server upload success, I already got that covered, I want to show a spinner when image is loading right after I click the "Choose file" button from the input file, is that possible?

I'm using Vue.

```
<label class="modal_input_image fs_normal c_dark" :for="field.id" :style="'background-image:url('+backgroundImage+');'"></label>
<input :id="field.id" type="file">
```

Comment: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/progress/

Comment: https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-progressbar

Comment: https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/progress/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) and [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) events on [file inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) - after the value of the file input changes, it should fire those events - try both, see which one suits your needs.

Show the 'loading' indicator when the event first fires, hide the indicator on server upload success!